# Error when running "ansible-container build"

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-container

I'm trying to build the Hello-World-Example from https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/getting_started.html. But when I'm running the command "sudo ansible-container build", I receive the following error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/flaskTest$ sudo ansible-container build
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
Building Docker Engine context...   
Starting Docker build of Ansible Container Conductor image (please be patient)...   
Parsing conductor CLI args.
Docker™ daemon integration engine loaded. Build starting.   project=hello-world
Building service... project=hello-world service=flask

PLAY [flask] *******************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [flask]

TASK [flask : Install dumb init] ***********************************************
changed: [flask]

TASK [flask : Install epel] ****************************************************
changed: [flask]

TASK [flask : Install pip] *****************************************************
changed: [flask]

TASK [flask : Create flask user] ***********************************************
changed: [flask]

TASK [flask : Copy source into container] **************************************
changed: [flask]

TASK [flask : Install Python dependencies] *************************************
changed: [flask]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
flask                      : ok=7    changed=6    unreachable=0    failed=0

Applied role to service role=flask service=flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/conductor", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ansible-container', 'console_scripts', 'conductor')()
  File "/_ansible/container/__init__.py", line 19, in __wrapped__
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/_ansible/container/cli.py", line 399, in conductor_commandline
    **params)
  File "/_ansible/container/__init__.py", line 19, in __wrapped__
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/_ansible/container/core.py", line 827, in conductorcmd_build
    with_name=is_last_role)
  File "/_ansible/container/docker/engine.py", line 105, in __wrapped__
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/_ansible/container/__init__.py", line 19, in __wrapped__
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/_ansible/container/docker/engine.py", line 682, in commit_role_as_layer
    return to_commit.commit(**commit_data).id
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py", line 111, in commit
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 131, in commit
    json=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 226, in _result
    self._raise_for_status(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 222, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request ("file with no instructions.")
Conductor terminated. Cleaning up.  command_rc=1 conductor_id=18f04765ed90f0ed5437728553e427cae5167d71b024b7e182b72d9db6a6fb8f save_container=False
ERROR   Conductor exited with status 1
```

To make sure I correctly build my ansible-container, I've also tried to build a working and finished example from https://github.com/rhuss/ansible-container-demo.
But again I receive the same Error-Message, when I try to build the ansible-container:

```
docker.errors.APIError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request ("file with no instructions.")
```

Does somebody understand the error-message and could help me resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to advance on this Denis? I am running into the same problem